# Update office document managed metadata on Sharepoint using C#

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, metadata, managed

I am trying to update the managed metadata fields of a listItem in SharePoint on premise. For most documents this works as intended. The only ones that do not work are xlsx, docx and pptx, so all the newer office formats.

The changes that I make to the columns in the code are just ignored and no value is displayed. Did anyone else encounter this problem and has a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to put the code up that is working for the other documents types

Comment: I used a simple "listItem[fieldname] = -1;#termLabel|termGuid" or something like that (not sure about the positioning of the ; and the #) since that was the solution most people were talking about in the threads I read. Somewhere else, someone told me to use the 'TaxonomyField.SetFieldValueByValue' method, and that works perfectly.